# Are discontinuous functions integrable? And integral of every continuous function continuous?

Tags: calculus, integration

According to me answer of second part is yes as integration simply means area under curve.

Answer (score 7):

> Is every discontinuous function integrable?

No. For example, consider a function that is $1$ on every rational point, and $0$ on every irrational point. What is the integral of this function from $0$ to $1$? It's not integrable! For any partition of $[0,1]$, every subinterval will have parts of the function at height $0$ and at height $1$, so there' no way to make the Riemann sums converge. *(However you might later encounter something called Lebesgue integration, where they would say this is integrable. Giving an explicit example of a non-Lebesgue integrable function is harder and more annoying. A good heuristic for such a function would be a function that is $1$ at every rational, and a random number between $-1$ and $1$ for every irrational point - somehow every more discontinuous than the previous example)*.

> Is the integral of every continuous function continuous?

Yes! In fact, this is a byproduct of what's commonly known as the [second fundamental theorem of calculus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondFundamentalTheoremofCalculus.html) (although logically it comes first).

Comment: David, let's say I integrate a function $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(s) \ ds$, what conditions must I have for the function F to be continuous?

Answer (score 6):

There is a theorem that says that a function is integrable if and only if the set of discontinuous points has "measure zero", meaning they can be covered with a collection of intervals of arbitrarily small total length.

Answer (score 0):

First question: yes some are of course (e.g. step functions).
Second: yes in fact Lipschitz continuous

Comment: I believe the integral is Lipschitz continuous only on an interval (not the entire real line), unless the function is bounded.

Comment: @user2566092: I agree, but of course the guy who posed the question didn't mention this, so he probably doesn't care about this anyways

Answer (score 0):

Every continuous function is integrable, but some discuntinuous functions are integrable and others aren't.

Moreover, there are two widely-used senses for the word 'integrable': 
Riemann's integrability and Lebesgue's integrability.